# Can Power View be viewed on the iPhone or iPad?

Tags: iphone, ipad, reporting-services, powerview

And if not, are there plans to provide support in the future (using HTML5/Canvas or other technology)? This could be a deal-breaker for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the info here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213579.aspx  "Power View is a browser-based Silverlight application launched" so unfortunately it won't run natively on iOS devices. The rest of your question I'll leave to Microsoft to answer.

Answer (score 0):

From what you can see [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=0vLLAdjGtrU#at=145), it is basically possible to use Power View on an iOS device (maybee with limited capabilities, see [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/ms156511.aspx)). However, I'm not sure how fare Microsoft is in the process of bringing its BI tools to mobile devices.

Anyone who has an update on that?